# Microsoft Edge Reading View Publisher detection

Tags: microsoft-edge

According to the Edge Reading View documentation at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/browser/reading-view

> It also looks for 'source_organization' and 'publisher' attributes in any html tag as a secondary indicator of publisher information on the page.

Can anyone show me a snippet of HTML which, using the above method (not the Open Graph meta header method), successfully injects a Publisher name into the Reading View?

Answer (score 0):

This feature seem to have been deprecated in Microsoft Edge as part of a recent redesign of Reader View. It now only shows the publisher’s domain name the same way Firefox does. Here is how you add other [metadata to reader mode](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/browser-reading-mode-metadata) in different web browsers, though.